# Where are Heroku apps hosted exactly?

Tags: heroku

Through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions I see that for heroku common runtime spaces heroku has two available regions: Europe and United States. But I couldn't find exactly in any official documentation which region exactly of United States heroku hosts the application. For example I want to know if it hosts on east, west, north, south.

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The Heroku US region is AWS's `us-east-1`.
EU is `eu-west-1`.

That makes the US region located in North Virginia, and EU in Ireland.

Answer (score 29):

As the URL you posted, just follow their command in your own terminal shell:

```
$ heroku regions --common
ID  Location       Runtime
──  ─────────────  ──────────────
eu  Europe         Common Runtime
us  United States  Common Runtime
```

Then use the `curl` as they suggest, just change the `/regions/frankfurt` to the region ID you want (i.e. `us`)

```
$ curl -n -X GET https://api.heroku.com/regions/us -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
{
  "country":"United States",
  "created_at":"2012-11-21T20:44:16Z",
  "description":"United States",
  "id":"59accabd-516d-4f0e-83e6-6e3757701145",
  "locale":"Virginia",
  "name":"us",
  "private_capable":false,
  "provider":{
    "name":"amazon-web-services",
    "region":"us-east-1"
  },
  "updated_at":"2016-08-09T22:03:28Z"
}
```

Here you are: `"locale":"Virginia"`

Damien got you the answer, I just reconfirm if there is any changes by running all those commands.

> The Heroku US region is AWS's us-east-1. EU is eu-west-1.
>
> That makes the US region located in North Virginia, and EU in Ireland.

Answer (score 24):

The other answers are great, but a simpler way to view the details about the regions is to run `heroku regions --common --json`, which outputs pretty formatted JSON:

```
[
  {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "created_at": "2013-09-19T01:29:12Z",
    "description": "Europe",
    "id": "ed30241c-ed8c-4bb6-9714-61953675d0b4",
    "locale": "Dublin",
    "name": "eu",
    "private_capable": false,
    "provider": {
      "name": "amazon-web-services",
      "region": "eu-west-1"
    },
    "updated_at": "2016-08-09T22:03:28Z"
  },
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "created_at": "2012-11-21T20:44:16Z",
    "description": "United States",
    "id": "59accabd-516d-4f0e-83e6-6e3757701145",
    "locale": "Virginia",
    "name": "us",
    "private_capable": false,
    "provider": {
      "name": "amazon-web-services",
      "region": "us-east-1"
    },
    "updated_at": "2016-08-09T22:03:28Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Regin EU details :

```
Country -> Ireland
City -> Dublin
AWS Region -> eu-west-1
```

Region US details :

```
Country -> United States
City -> Virginia
AWS Region -> us-east-1
```

Comment: In addition to the US and EU, there are 3 other regions Australia, Germany, and Japan